# How to call the new command SVNRDUMP (Subversion 1.7) through PHP?

Tags: php, svn

I have a PHP client and want to communicate with Subversion server using cURL & WebDav. Please guide me how to write PHP code to do something like svnrdump tool offers?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the [SVN library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.svn.php) that comes with PHP. All the `svndump` tool does is to just get each individual changeset and apply it to a new repository, so you'd probably want to use [svn_repos_create](http://php.net/svn_repos_create), then use [svn_log](http://php.net/svn_log) to find the number of changesets to download, then a combination of svn_checkout on the remote repository and svn_checkin to apply the changeset to your new repository, followed by duplicating the message.

Edit: There is also a method called [svn_repos_hotcopy](http://php.net/svn_repos_hotcopy) which may do all of the above. Unfortunately, there is no documentation at all. My guess is that this maps to the c function in SVN, and you can [view the source code](http://www.google.com/codesearch#vBCMLKCvFQ4/trunk/subversion/libsvn_repos/repos.c&ct=rc&cd=2&q=svn_repos_hotcopy&l=1722) to see if this would help you (my guess is yes, assuming the PHP call works).

Comment: I haven't tried your approach since it looks complicated. Could I just run it with shell_exec?

Comment: Sure, you could do that too using the exec method. Be very careful to sanitise your inputs to make sure that the user can't inject any code into the shell that exec creates.

Comment: There is another thing, when I installed Subversion on my OS (Ubuntu) I can't find the svnrdump command. Do you know where it is or how to get it running on Linux?

Comment: Sorry, the command you want is `svnsync`, not `svndump`. This is part of the standard svn distribution.

Comment: No, it is the new command [svnrdump](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html) which goes with Subversion 1.7. It dumps the whole repository into just one file. I can't find document about that tool and cannot find it in linux subversion package as well :(